# Why does scaling down a deployment seem to always remove the newest pods?

Tags: kubernetes

(Before I start, I'm using minikube v27 on Windows 10.)

I have created a deployment with the nginx 'hello world' container with a desired count of 2:

[image: pods before scaling up]

I actually went into the '2 hours' old pod and edited the index.html file from the welcome message to "broken" - I want to play with k8s to seem what it would look like if one pod was 'faulty'.

If I scale this deployment up to more instances and then scale down again, I almost expected k8s to remove the oldest pods, but it consistently removes the newest:

[image: pods after scaling down]

How do I make it remove the oldest pods first?

(Ideally, I'd like to be able to just say "redeploy everything as the exact same version/image/desired count in a rolling deployment" if that is possible)

Comment: Most of the larger-problem answers I've seen to this question have involved putting something in the pod spec that will change – use version-tagged images and never "latest", Helm-generated hashes of the ConfigMap content as annotations.  It's still a good question.

Comment: @DavidMaze Even if I can 'trick' it into thinking the pod has changed, I'll be surprised if there's no simple way to do this. Scaling events keeping the oldest pods feels like the restaurant filling up their cooked rice pot with fresh but leaving the old on the bottom. It makes sense to rotate, surely? Especially if the pods are identical which they are...

Comment: The pods are identical. Why do you care? From a purely performance point of view, newer pods are potentially less warmed-up (less data in the cache etc.), so it makes sense to remove them first. If your pods degrade over time, then scaling down isn't a solution to that issue.

Comment: @NeilTrodden how does it "make sense"? What if the pods are running an in-memory cache like Redis or Memcached, and this cache has been fully populated with values after running the past few hours, if you scale your deployment up and down do you really want k8s to remove your fully-populated caches and replace them with caches that have only been up for a few minutes? You should never ever SSH into your pods and edit any data in them directly, use a mounted volume if you need to persist data between pod restarts or changes.

Comment: @NeilTrodden if you want k8s to automatically purge pods that have been corrupted in some way then implement an application-level health check, more info here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/k8s201/#application-health-checking

Comment: @kfedorov91 I only sshed in so I could simulate a problem. I think I agree with you though, I'm thinking about solving problems manually, and I don't scale - I shouldn't be thinking about 'fixing' issues in the cluster, I should provide proper healthchecks - and I didn't realise they could be defined by me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Pod deletion preference is based on a ordered series of checks, defined in code here:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.11/pkg/controller/controller_utils.go#L737

Summarizing- precedence is given to delete pods:

- that are unassigned to a node, vs assigned to a node
- that are in pending or not running state, vs running
- that are in not-ready, vs ready
- that have been in ready state for fewer seconds
- that have higher restart counts
- that have newer vs older creation times

These checks are not directly configurable.

Given the rules, if you can make an old pod to be not ready, or cause an old pod to restart, it will be removed at scale down time before a newer pod that is ready and has not restarted.

There is discussion around use cases for the ability to control deletion priority, which mostly involve workloads that are a mix of job and service, here:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/45509

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I might not be doing k8s right just yet but I had to know it was deliberate logic being applied.

Comment: Those bullets seem right except for the last one. In particular, it undermines any preferential affinity you might have on your pods. And it flies in the face of the fact that running on VMs and on Kubernetes has the advantage of restarting old things, which tend to have more failures and worse performance.

Comment: Direct link to the feature which came from that discussion: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/#pod-deletion-cost

Comment: There is a newer logic applied now, which includes spreading the pods across nodes and uses the log of the uptime - see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.23/pkg/controller/controller_utils.go#L810 and https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/tree/master/keps/sig-apps/2185-random-pod-select-on-replicaset-downscale.

Answer (score -1):

what about this :

1. kubectl scale deployment ingress-nginx-controller --replicas=2
2. Wait until 2 replicas are up.
3. kubectl delete pod ingress-nginx-controller-oldest-replica
4. kubectl scale deployment ingress-nginx-controller --replicas=1

I experienced zero downtime doing so while removing oldest pod.